# Screen went Blank after switching the version of OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I drew a white triangle in the screen(WIDTH=800,HEIGHT=600). I got the white screen sized triangle, working perfectly fine with OpenGl version 4.2.0 - Build 10.18.10.3496 (current version)

but when I switched to 3.3.0 - Build 10.18.10.3496
I got nothing but black blank screen. When I again went for 4.2.0, everything is just working fine.
I have no idea what's going on?

```
public abstract  class Window {

public static void createNormalVersion(int width,int height,String title){

try {
Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(width, height));
Display.setTitle(title);
Display.create();

} catch (LWJGLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
System.exit(0);

 }
}

public static void createSpecifiedVersion
(int width,int height,String title,int firstVer,int secondVer){

try{
PixelFormat pixel=new PixelFormat();
ContextAttribs context=new ContextAttribs(firstVer,secondVer)
.withForwardCompatible(true)
.withProfileCore(true);

Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(width,height));
Display.setTitle(title);
Display.create(pixel,context);

}catch(LWJGLException e){
e.printStackTrace();
}

  }


// I choose the version from main method
public static void main(String[] args) {

Window.createSpecifiedVersion(WIDTH, HEIGHT, TITLE, 3, 3);
MainComponent game = new MainComponent();
game.start();
}
```

Comment: You might use some feature which isn't available in GL3.30. You should post the relevant code (client side and shaders). Maybe it is simply the `#version` directive in your shader sources.

Comment: Was your original attempt `.withProfileCore(true)` as well? This sort of thing will happen in a core profile if you don't bind a Vertex Array Object. If that is the case, you'll find `glGetError (...)` returns `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`. In fact, your question does not discuss checking error codes at all.